# error in mysql im trying to import the database

Tags: sql, database, syntax, phpmyadmin

[can you please help me on this im trying to import this database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8HDX.png)

the sentences is set as link with picture

Comment: Could you please share few initial lines of your SQL file?

Comment: https://snag.gy/MprohK.jpg  this is the error after i try import  again

Comment: So before importing, click on a database name (on the left side) or create a database then select it so that MySQL knows where you want to export.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the first line of your dump. The "--" is missing at the beginning of the line.